# ReactJs responsive indexed text everytime it goes into a new line

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've got some text like 
"Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor "

I would like to index all the lines when they goes into a new line like that: 
**1  #  Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet 
 2 # Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum 
 3 # Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem ipsum docet constructor Lorem[image]**

 and so on....

I've found someone targeting ('\n') with split('\n') method to split the string into an array of strings and adding index + # + linetext. 
 But that's not my case since my text doesn't have \n tags to target. In addition i want it to be responsive with the width of the div, so when that width changes, and text modifies into more or less new lines, indexes change aswell.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

This is my snippet code:

```js
const TextArea = ({isActive, isInsideFileActive}) => {
  return (
    <>
        <h5 >
            {files.find((file) => file.id === isActive)?.innerFiles?.map((singleFile, i) => {
                if (singleFile.name === isInsideFileActive)
                {
                return <div key={i}>{singleFile.text}</div>
                }
            })}
        </h5>
    </>
  )
}
```